# In C# I am trying to show number of days between 2 datetime pickers, inclusive of days selected but it does not add 1 day if I select todays date

Tags: c#, date, time, timespan, picker

If I begin on todays date and count on 5 days, it displays 4 days. If I move the start date back 1, it displays 6
Here is what I currently have and works except if I use todays date as the start date.

```
private void DaysToShow() 
{
    //Find the difference in the days selected in the drop down menu so we can calculate
    DateTime dtDateOnQuay = dtpDateOnQuay.Value;
    DateTime dtDateLeft = dtpDateLeft.Value;
    TimeSpan difference = dtDateLeft - dtDateOnQuay;

    //As the days are inclusive and the above gets the days in between, add 1
    m_iDaysRent = difference.Days + 1;
    m_iDaysDetention = m_iDaysRent;

    if (dtpDateReturned.Checked)
    {
        TimeSpan oDetentionDiff = dtpDateReturned.Value - dtpDateOnQuay.Value;
        m_iDaysDetention = oDetentionDiff.Days + 1;
    }

    txtDaysOnQuay.Text = m_iDaysRent.ToString();
    txtDaysDetention.Text = m_iDaysDetention.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and specify the programming language you're using in the tags

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem might be the time perspective of the dates. You don't need it so you should probably try something like the solution below.

Check the DaysToShowByDateComp which ignores the time.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("2019-10-01 23:59:59");
        DateTime startDate2 = DateTime.Parse("2019-10-04 00:00:00");
        DateTime endDate2 = DateTime.Parse("2019-10-01 00:00:00");

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(endDate.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("With today timespan:" + DaysToShowByTimeComp(DateTime.Now, endDate));        
        Console.WriteLine("With today date comparison:" + DaysToShowByDateComp(DateTime.Now, endDate));

        Console.WriteLine("With other timespan:" + DaysToShowByTimeComp(startDate2, endDate2));     
        Console.WriteLine("With other date comparison:" + DaysToShowByDateComp(startDate2, endDate2));
    }

    private static int DaysToShowByTimeComp(DateTime start, DateTime end) 
    {
        //Find the difference in the days selected in the drop down menu so we can calculate
        DateTime dtDateOnQuay = end;
        DateTime dtDateLeft = start;
        TimeSpan difference = dtDateLeft - dtDateOnQuay;

        //As the days are inclusive and the above gets the days in between, add 1
        return difference.Days + 1;
    }

    private static int DaysToShowByDateComp(DateTime start, DateTime end) 
    {
        return (int)((start.Date - end.Date).TotalDays) + 1;
    }
}
```

The output would be

```
10/4/2019 2:18:23 PM 
10/1/2019 11:59:59 PM 
With today timespan: 3 
With today date comparison: 4 
With other timespan: 4
With other date comparison: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the math operator and converted to an int as below and now working

```
    private void DaysToShow() 
        {
        //Find the difference in the days selected in the drop down menu so we can         calculate
        DateTime dtDateOnQuay = dtpDateOnQuay.Value;
        DateTime dtDateLeft = dtpDateLeft.Value; 
        TimeSpan difference = dtDateLeft.Subtract(dtDateOnQuay);

        //As the days are inclusive and the above gets the days in between, add 1
        m_iDaysRent = Convert.ToInt32(difference.TotalDays) +1;  
        m_iDaysDetention = m_iDaysRent;

        if (dtpDateReturned.Checked)
        {
            TimeSpan oDetentionDiff = dtpDateReturned.Value - dtpDateOnQuay.Value;
            m_iDaysDetention = oDetentionDiff.Days + 1;
        }

        txtDaysOnQuay.Text = m_iDaysRent.ToString();
        txtDaysDetention.Text = m_iDaysDetention.ToString();
    }
```